# What are the arguments against the idea that God will condemn non-believers to Hell even if they do more good than Christians?

Tags: judgment, non-christians, righteousness, sodom

The background of this question is in the conversation Abraham and God has over the inhabitants of Sodom. God is focusing on whether anyone within the city of Sodom is **good or righteous**, God doesn't care if they know him. You have most probably seen lots of people who are non-believers engage in humanitarian works of charity that supercede those of regular Christians. If God is to use the same criteria he used with the inhabitants of Sodom, can we be assured that these non-believers will  be deemed good and worthy of heaven? Jesus said when you did it to them you did it to me, so aren't these non-believers doing good to Jesus, who will send them to life?

Comment: @User14, but they have refused to believe in his one and only begotten son. So no life

Comment: Sad that we are not allowed to deal with important questions like this.  I think it can be appropriately answered by summarizing the arguments for and against. Such an approach will improve the relevance of C.se to readers IMO. I will try to edit it so that it is not opinion-based.

Comment: @Dan Fefferman, yes this question is very important and would like the community to vote to reopen

Comment: @Peter Turner is apparently the moderator who closed this. Hopefully he will notice the changes and re-open it now. If you would like to get answers from the other side of the question, you can ask  a separate question: "what are the arguments in favor" with appropriate adjustments to the rest of the text. Personally I'd prefer "what are the arguments for and against" but if I recall correctly that is still considered opinion based.

Comment: @DanFefferman, Okay

Comment: Sorry my close note didn't get posted for some reason,  we can't ask questions on the site that can be answered from multiple conflicting viewpoints.  There's no way this is going to have the same answer from unitarians as from Baptists. Why not stick to a denomination and ask what they think about it? What we do not want is a collection of Bible verses to answer any given question

Comment: Lot is called righteous (2 Peter 2:7-8) even though the account of his life is not a stellar example of good behavior.  Someone without a correct relationship with God cannot do good because whatever is not of faith is sin.

Answer (score 1):

It is wickedness to deny God and boast of your own good works as though God we’re not involved. In other words, it’s not putting God into perspective: to deny God far outweighs “righteous deeds” by a long shot. If you do not see this, then you have not correctly judged what is important. To Jesus, the heart is what matters. There were prostitutes He called “daughter” and Pharisees He called “sons of the Devil.”

This is because righteousness is always justified by faith, whether in the new or the old testament. That’s why God judged Lot as righteous, because he had faith in God. Similarly with Abraham. Deeds are secondary. We all have a sin nature—but our faith is what speaks of where are hearts are. And especially love—Jesus says, “have faith in God” or in some translations, “have faith *from* God.” In other words, can it really be faith without the love of God?

***“So we have come to know and to believe the love that God has for us. God is love, and whoever abides in love abides in God, and God abides in him.”*** (1 John 4:17)

Comment: But God who does not change, didn't care if the inhabitants of Sodom knew him. He just checked if they were just

Comment: @FewAgainstMany-Israel let me get back to you on that

Comment: Someone is suffering right now. Let's say person A is starving, will God bless the one who doesn't accept Jesus and passes on or the one who is a non believer and gives person A bread?

Comment: In that case, remember that God is love. He who has love abides in God and God in him, regardless of whether he technically knows about Jesus or not.

Comment: True, that satisfies me.

Comment: @FewAgainstMany-Israel Abraham believed God and it was credited to him for righteousness. God was not looking at Sodom to see if there were any people there who didn't know him but we're doing good things. He was looking for any righteous and the righteous one lives by faith.